# Access GCDAsyncSocket read queue

Tags: ios, twisted, gcdasyncsocket

I'm using GCDAsyncSocket library for my iOS messaging app with Twisted Server in the backend. Everything is setup fine and works fine, but I found out about a peculiar situation when it doesn't work fine. So, my server is architectured in such a way that when the user is offline, all his message are cached on server and when he's detected online, the server sends to him all his cached pending messages at once.

Now, GCDAsyncSocket uses internal read and write queues, so here, those sent pending-messages by the server are queued by the read queue until they're read by the delegate method `-(void)socket:didReadData:withTag:` Now, in my app, this delegate method processes the incoming messages and displays them in a tableview one by one. So, the point of problem is that whenever the delegate method is reading from the queue, if you suspend the app, all the unprocessed messages in the read queue are lost. So to counter this, I want to access the read queue so that I can save its contents before app suspension so that I can recover it when app is opened again.

**Note**: As per my understanding, the lost messages are from the queue and not the server because the server shows "all messages sent" even before the delegate reaches half of the messages while processing. And after that if suspended, then this problem persists.

So am I doing it the wrong way? Or is there any way to access the queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider adding an acknowledgement step to your protocol.  Instead of letting the server send all queued messages and then immediately forget them, you could have it remember them until the client sends back a per-message acknowledgement.

This way, no matter what the client does between receiving a particular message and displaying it to the user, that message will always be available for re-delivery from the server.  Only after the client has viewed (and therefore acknowledged) the message will the server forget it (and thus not re-transmit it to the client the next time the client shows up).

You can do this pretty easily by assigning unique identifiers to messages.  These might be random UUIDs or - if your message deliver must always be in order - sequence numbers.  Sequence numbers are convenient (if they make sense for your application) because by acknowledging a single message sequence number your client can indicate that it has processed several messages (because if it always processes them in order then any message with an earlier sequence number must have been processed too).

The failure mode for this strategy is the opposite as the failure mode for your current strategy.  Now, when the phone suspends before a message is pulled from the receive queue, it is lost.  Using acknowledgements, the message cannot be lost until it has been processed (displayed).  However, you might display the message and then fail to send the acknowledgement somehow.  This will lead to a message being displayed twice.

You can narrow the window for this failure by also recording information on the phone about which messages have been processed (displayed).  If the phone receives a message from the server that it knows it has already displayed then it can skip displaying it and just re-send the acknowledgement to allow the server to forget it.

This reduces the failure window to just the time between when you display a message and when you manage to record locally that that message has been displayed (or the opposite order, if you prefer the failure mode where messages are lost rather than where they are displayed twice).

Comment: Thanks for the work-around Jean-Paul. Actually, I have already implemented something close to this, and currently my prototype is using that itself. What I'm doing is sending a "getnext" signal from my app everytime it successfully receives a pending-message. This "getnext" signal retrieves the next message queued up in the queue at the server. The server sends "empty" if the queue is exhausted. Whenever the client receives "empty" it stops sending the "getnext" signal.

Comment: Now, this works brilliantly, but the nature of my app is slightly different (I'm not at the liberty to disclose that). What I can say is that it requires that data very fast. After several tests, the above mentioned work-around proved to be slow when I hosted the server on the internet (During development on localhost, it worked fast for obvious reasons). So, what I think is that, this to and fro of messages for each pending message is proving to be very slow and that's why I need all messages to be sent at once. Hence, if there was a way to access the read queue, I could save it.

Comment: I really wish I could've marked your answer correct for that wonderful explanation you provided, but I think this problem is more of a client-side than server-side. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Jean-Paul Calderone, always there with a nice answer, here or on the mailing list.. you got my respect man.. I still remember the first answer you gave me on the list about logging, good times ;)

Comment: @user3777326, the solution you described is a request/response solution where the client pulls messages from the server.  This incurs round-trip latency for every message.  This is not the solution I described.  I described a solution where the server continues to push messages down to the client at whatever rate you wish (fast or slow, whatever).  The only change is that you introduce an extra step where the client tells the server when it is *done* with each message.  This lets the server know if it ever needs to retransmit a message because the client lost it before it was done using it.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone, okay, now I get the point you're trying to make. What I understood earlier was that the server sends the next message only if it receives the acknowledgement of the previous message. But what you really meant was that the client should send acknowledgement for each message, and the server should resend messages only for which ACK is not received. Am I getting it right this time?

Comment: If yes, giving a thought to your solution, can I do something like, a counter is there on client side which counts the received pending-messages, and sends the "count" to server on suspension, or sends "empty" if all are received. The server then resends the remaining if it receives a count else it clears the array if it receives pending.

Comment: If the server receives "count", it will resend all messages starting from the "count" that it receives. In this strategy, I wouldn't have to implement sequence numbers and change a lot of code. Do you find any flaws in this @Jean-PaulCalderone apart from the ones you already mentioned in your original answer?

Comment: How does it know which message corresponds to the "count" value?  It sounds like that approach is basically the same as implementing message sequence numbers - so I guess it will work. :)

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: Private protocol which will give the identity of the client, the method:"count", and the count itself. So maybe I'll test it out now and mark your answer accepted if everything goes as planned. If not, I'll bother you some more till I get it working right. ;)  Thanks for the healthy discussion! :)

Comment: @Jean-Paul Calderone: So I tried out the above solution. But before I could analyze the original problem, I ended up with another. On detection of the client online, I send out all the pending-messages from a list using a while loop. And this seems to be blocking. Because when in the loop, if at that time someone sends a message, it is received only after the loop completes.

Comment: So I looked for solutions for non-blocking ways to implement something like a loop, and I found 2-3 questions on stack overflow which have been answered by you. Out of them, I tried the "reactor.spawnProcess()" do this sending on init, but it seemd a bit complex for me to understand. Do I need to spawn entire process just for implementing one method in another thread? I couldn't find any thread implementation. Can you help me figure out what can be applied here just to perform one method in another thread? Should I create a new question for this?

Comment: Twisted's network I/O is non-blocking.  You need neither processes nor threads.  Maybe ask a new question and include some of the code from your loop and someone might explain what's going on.

Comment: @Jean-Paul Calderone: So you mean to say that a while() loop in dataReceived() wont block the server and would allow other users to interact with the server while that loop is running? If that's so, then maybe I need to go over the twisted fundamentals again!

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty sure we're talking past each other at this point.  I suggest opening some new questions with some code samples so there's something concrete to discuss.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: New question up. Can you please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329492/alternative-to-a-while-loop-in-twisted-which-doesnt-block-the-reactor-thread) .Thanks for all the help you've provided until now. :)