# Alternative to a while loop in twisted which doesn't block the reactor thread

Tags: python, twisted

I'm making a chat application in twisted. Suppose my server is designed in such a way that whenever it detects a client online, it sends the client all the pending-messages (those messages of that client which were cached in a python-list on the server because it was offline) one-by-one in a while loop until the list is exhausted. Something like this:

```
class MyChat(LineReceiver):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)

        while True: 
            #retrieve first message from a list of pending-messages(queue) of "self" 
            msg = self.retrieveFromQueue(self)      
            if msg != "empty":
                self.transport.write(msg)       
            else:
                break

    def lineReceived(self, line):
    ...

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
    ...  

    def retrieveFromQueue(self, who):
        msglist = []                                                        

        if who in self.factory.userMessages:
            msglist = self.factory.userMessages[who]

        if msglist != []:
            msg = msglist.pop(0)              #msglist is a list of strings

            self.factory.userMessages[self] = msglist               

            return msg
        else:
            return "empty"  


    factory.userMessages = {}   #dict of list of incoming messages of users who aren't online
```

So according to my understanding of Twisted, the while loop will block the main reactor thread and any interaction from any other client with the server will not be registered by the server. If that's the case, I want an alternate code/method to this approach which will not block the twisted thread.

**Update:** There may be 2000-3000 pending messages per user because of the nature of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2011/11/blocking-vs-running.html addresses this point.

The answer here depends on what exactly `self.retrieveFromQueue(self)` does.  You implied it's something like:

```
if self.list_of_messages:
    return self.list_of_messages.pop(0)
return b"empty"
```

If this is the case, then the answer is one thing.  On the other hand, if the implementation is something more like:

```
return self.remote_mq_client.retrieve_queue_item(self.queue_identifier)
```

then the answer might be something else entirely.  However, note that it's the implementation of `retrieveFromQueue` upon which the answer appears to hinge.

That there is a `while` loop isn't quite as important.  The `while` loop reflects the fact that (to use Glyph's words), this code **is getting work done**.

You may decide that the amount of work this loop represents is too great to all get done at one time.  If there are hundreds of millions of queued messages then copying them one by one into the connection's send buffer will probably use both a noticable amount of time and memory.  In this case, you may wish to consider the producer/consumer pattern and [its support in Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/producers.html).  This won't make the code any less (or more) "blocking" but it will make it run for shorter periods of time at a time.

So the questions to answer here are really:

- whether or not `retrieveFromQueue` blocks
- if it does not block, whether or not there will be so many queued messages that processing them all will cause `connectionMade` to run for so long that other clients notice a disruption in service

Comment: I have updated the question as per the information you needed. retrieveFromQueue() is of the former type of the two you mentioned.

Comment: Okay.  I guess you'd like more hints based on that? :)

Comment: Yea!! So if these are the cases, do I need an alternative to the current implementation for the server to remain interactive(and what?) or will the current strategy work?

Comment: Some hints please? Should I use threading to run that loop? Because according to my tests, if there are like 1000-2000 messages, then the server becomes somewhat unresponsive to other users till that loop completes.